# how add properties to relationship in neo4j?

Tags: python, neo4j, bigdata, spring-data-neo4j

i use this code to get distance between two point using latitude and longtitude , and i want use this return values for put as relationship property between two nodes(hotel & me)
code:///////

```
MATCH (u:me)-[d:distance]->(n:Hotels)
WITH
  point({longitude: u.longitude, latitude: u.latitude}) AS trainPoint,
  point({longitude: n.longitude, latitude: n.latitude}) AS officePoint            
RETURN round(point.distance(trainPoint, officePoint)) AS travelDistance
```

i want to add the return values to relationship distance

Answer (score 1):

You can use SET to add a property to a relationship (or a node).  See here: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/set/

For your example:

```
MATCH (u:me)-[d:distance]->(n:Hotels)
WITH d,
  point({longitude: u.longitude, latitude: u.latitude}) AS trainPoint,
  point({longitude: n.longitude, latitude: n.latitude}) AS officePoint            
WITH d, round(point.distance(trainPoint, officePoint)) AS travelDistance
SET d.travelDistance = travelDistance
RETURN d
```